# Single word for a self-confessed traveler who constantly talks about his travels regardless of the audience interest, circumstance or relevence?

Tags: single-word-requests, neologisms

What would be a good single word for a self-confessed traveler who constantly talks about his travels, rattling off place names ("Oh that one time in Timbaktu....", "Thank you for the coffee! Speaking of coffee, the best mocha I've ever had was at this coffee shop in Addis Ababaa...."), prone to self-aggrandizement and having a tendency to hog the show everytime, dispensing free travel-advice, exotic restaurant reviews and like regardless of the audience interest, circumstance or relevance?

Neologisms, humorous & creative wordplays will be appreciated!

Comment: Does this egotistical windbag who loves the sound of his own voice have to be a *self-confessed* traveler?

Comment: I can't think of a single word. But have heard of the  term "when we/I". A _wheni_ will constantly refer to their previous experiences they find humurous or important, though not always travel related. Maybe _anecdotaholic_ ?

Comment: There was a cartoon character named [Commander McBragg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commander_McBragg) in the 1960s and the early 1970s who possessed some of the characteristics you describe in your question—terrible windbag, great traveler, full-tilt self-aggrandizer, utter lack of concern for the captive status of his audience—so that two-word name might be a good match. I agree with medica, though, that your question would be better off if you either changed _self-confessed_ to _self-aggrandizing_ in the head and body of your question or dropped the modifier altogether.

Comment: Cliff Clavin the know-it-all postman from *Cheers*. I think he spent entire season 4 talking about his trip in Florida.

Comment: Duplicate of [Word for disrespecting eldest half-sister by referring to her husband as girly-girl-manly-boy though he's amused but the rest of the family isn’t?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/word-for-disrespecting-eldest-half-sister-by-referring-to-her-husband-as-girly-g)

Comment: Solipsistourist.

Comment: @tchrist. I can see why someone might think there's a single word (or, at least, a standard term) for this one. It's basically a *location namedropper*.

Comment: Related: [Can anything be done about mean-spirited requests for terminology?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4842)

Comment: In an old Reader's Digest joke, a person was described as suffering from **Jet Brag**.  Its memorable as a noun.

Comment: "Jet brag" is better than the answers so far, I would argue, particularly since it has been seen "in the wild" and addresses the OP's issue specifically.

Comment: Isn't that just a variation on "oral diarrhea"?

Answer (score 21):

The person is a bore. I can't think of a type of bore specific to travel but if you would accept a hyphenated one I suggest travel-bore, which I have occasionally heard used.

Comment: +1 “Bore, n.: A person who talks when you wish him to listen.”—Ambrose Bierce

Comment: A bore is boring, i.e. uninteresting. This person sounds interesting, being both well-traveled and talkative, so I would probably never call them a bore. The asker is more interested in the way this person provides unsolicited advice and stories in a proud, almost boastful manner.

Comment: @talmu `prone to self-aggrandizement and having a tendency to hog the show everytime, dispensing free travel-advice ... regardless of the audience interest, circumstance or relevance.` I think the answer fits very well. "Travel bore" (I have seen it more without the hyphen) is something of a fixed phrase, so much that sometimes people who enjoy travel (but aren't boring) wittily refer to themselves as travel bores.

Comment: Bore, boor, or some combination of the two?

Answer (score 11):

I can't come up with something travel-specific, but this may help:

The late Sir Christopher Lee was described as a **long-winded raconteur** in his obituary in the [Telegraph](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/obituaries/11663342/Sir-Christopher-Lee-obituary.html).

> Throughout his career he had a reputation for being a **long-winded raconteur** whose reminiscences tended to focus on himself. In 1976, when Lee left Britain for the US, the move prompted an acquaintance to joke that **“the population of Los Angeles were dusting out their bomb shelters in anticipation of a barrage of anecdotes”**. According to another account, on one occasion an actress got off an aircraft looking ashen and exhausted. Questioned about her health by airport staff, she explained that she had been seated next to Lee and that he had not stopped talking about himself during the 10-hour flight.

Answer (score 4):

For a (possible) neologism, can I suggest:

### Travelogeur

It comes up in Websters' Third New International Dictionary as a noun according to [findwords.info](http://findwords.info/term/traveloguer).

[Wordow.com](http://www.wordow.com/english/dictionary/?t=traveloguers) defines it as:

> 'the author of a travelogue'.

There is also an attractive similarity to words like 'raconteur' (as previously answered) and '[logorrhoea](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/logorrhoea)', so maybe there is some scope for this word to take on the pejorative aspects that you are after!

Then I thought of:

### Touristista

This word is little-used, even on the internet. It crops up on [Instagram](http://www.oninstagram.com/touristista).

I think we could get there from the more-recognized [fashionista](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fashionista). I think fashionista certainly has pejorative overtones.

Four years ago a venue was described as

> another pre-fab consumo-touristista magnet

in a [blog comment](http://busblog.tonypierce.com/2011/11/people-like-food-trucks.html). I love that.

Comment: *Travelogeur* sounds pretentious enough that such a person would enjoy using it to describe themselves. +1!

Answer (score 3):

I tentatively suggest *braggart*, or *travel-braggart*; the same way Anton appended "travel" to "bore".

I tried to come up with something in the vein of the long-standing Swedish tradition of suffixing a given name to a noun/verb/adjective to form a pejorative: some common ones are *skrytmåns*, *viktigpetter* and *dummerjöns*, which means (literally, and respectively) "Brag-Magnus", "Important-Pete" (essentially, a "smart ass") and "Dumb-John" (a moron). It just doesn't translate very well. "Benny Bumptious"?

Answer (score 3):

A good suggestion in my opinion would be **rambler**, due to the two related meanings of 'to ramble'.
From [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ramble):

> **Ramble**
> 1- Walk for pleasure in the countryside:
> *'I spent most of my spare time rambling and climbing'*
>
> 2- Talk or write at length in a confused or inconsequential way:
> *'Willy rambled on about Norman archways'*

Whilst in the first case **rambler** might not encompass travelling to other countries, I can definitely see it being used in this way; "They went rambling all over Europe" wouldn't have to imply actually walking.

Additionally, rambling in the latter sense fails to capture the bragging aspect of the desired phrase, but absolutely captures the talking regardless of audience interest part.

Comment: This is more of a witty comment than an answer to the question, as the joke would be unintelligible without context. A rambler is a walker. To stretch that meaning to include international travel is a bit much. "Travel Bore" is a much better answer.

Answer (score 0):

The “know-it-all” sense of “[wisenheimer](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wisenheimer)” (Wiktionary) makes it a possible candidate to add to “travel-[wise]” to give “**travel-wisenheimer**,” with the “with reference to” sense of [-wise](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/-wise) to boot (Wordreference).

Answer (score 0):

How about an **Expedition Exhibitionist** (made it up per guidelines, exhibitionist = a person who behaves in an extravagant way in order to attract attention)

Or maybe a **Kay-yakker** or **Kay-yapper** which combines the travel site Kayak with yakker or yapper (both terms for someone who won't shut up)

Answer (score 0):

Not travel-specific, but I might call such a person "full of themself", or, if I was swearing, a "wanker".